# Proof of Leibniz integral rule for 2 variable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was preparing for Analysis exam and came across this exercise in one of the past exams.

Suppose $f: [a,b]\times[a,b] \to \Bbb R $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}: [a,b]\times[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ are continuous.

Prove that $F: [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$F(t)=\int_a^t f(x,t)\ dx,\; t \in [a,b]$$ is differentiable and find $F'(t)$.

I think that I can use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to find the derivative of $F(t)$
$$F'(t)=\int_a^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\ dx + f(t,t)$$
but I don't understand the proof that is on Wikipedia. Specifically, why we need to use delta increments to apply MVT? 
Is there perhaps a version that is easier to understand?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. What part of the proof didn't you understand?

Comment: The part about delta increments in the proof. Why do we need to use them to apply MVT? Also, where the non-integral part of the result comes from? I don't clearly see why taking the limit leads to there?

Comment: Does [this one](http://math.hawaii.edu/~rharron/teaching/MAT203/LeibnizRule.pdf) help? (It uses Fubini's theorem)

Comment: Yes, in a sense that is understandable, but it doesn't help me to solve the question, since it doesn't deal with functions of t in the limits of integration.